# Remote Desktop to a user while still logged on

Tags: remote-desktop, user

Is there a way to connect remotely to another user while there is a user still on the same PC.
So one PC with users and both of them logged in at the same time, one locally and one remotely?

Sorry i didn't explain my question very well, I don't mean 2 users viewing the same screen. I mean 2 user accounts. Say UserA is sitting at the desk on his account. and then UserB is on his account account but it remotely connecting to it. So they both have different desktops in front on their respective screens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, Microsoft Windows desktop OS (XP, Vista, 7) do not allow for multiple simultaneous session. Only Windows Server (with Terminal Server) allows for that. A limited number of remote desktop session are allowed by default with every Windows Server license.

On Windows XP their were report of successfully setting it using DLLs from Windows Server. It is an ugly hack. You can find the instructions at a [couple](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/06/13/enable-multiple-concurrent-remote-desktop-connections-or-sessions-in-windows-xp/) of [places](http://www.golod.com/2005/10/enabling-multiple-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows-xp-professional-and-media-center-edition-2005/).

Comment: I've used those hacks (under vista SP1) and it worked well, until SP2 came along and 'fixed' the hack. ;)

Comment: Wouldn't it violate the license agreement to do this with MS Windows?

Answer (score 2):

VNC can do this, so long as the remote session does not lock the keyboard and mouse of the machine.

I have had great success with [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/).

[image: VNC screenshot found via Google Images on freeware365.com]

Some sourceforge VNC projects include [UltraVNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ultravnc/) and [TightVNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vnc-tight/), both of which I have used successfully.  Please understand that I have not used either of these recently, however.  My only complaint back in the day was their lack of polish.

Comment: I've used UltraVNC with no problems - it's great!

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

[TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com) can do this and performs excellent. No fiddling with port forwarding or any of that. Just ensure your partner has the program running and ask for his ID and password:

[image]

TeamViewer is freeware.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to VNC, there are a couple of other web based services that allow this:  [Go To My PC](http://gotomypc.com) and [LogMeIn](http://logmein.com) are two I have used with great success in the past, though neither allow simultaneous log ins on their free versions.  You have to upgrade to the paid services to allow that.